# Termcap with parameters

Tags: c, shell, termcap

I am coding a shell-like in C and I want to implement the line edition functionality, I already implemented the basic of it, now I want to implement ctrl+l which clear the screen then display the prompt and the line I was working on.

I need to use the termcap :

'cm' String to position the cursor at line l, column c.

My question is how to I pass the variable l and c to the termcap ?

Comment: maybe this would help: http://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_chapter/termcap_2.html#SEC16

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have the `cm` capability stored in the `term_cm` variable. Then you would substitute parameters using the `tgoto` function:

```
char *s = tgoto (term_cm, c, l);
tputs (s, 1, putchar);
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear the screen use this :

```
write(1, tgetstr("cl", 0), strlen(tgetstr("cl", 0)));
```